# Connect to Elasticsearch running on gcp instance

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

I have a small gcp instance running elasticsearch (on port 9200) and cerebro (on port 9000). I have created firewall rules allowing connection to those 2 ports.

From my workstation I can access "http://instance_external_ip:9000" and I can get into the cerebro UI.

But if I try to curl "http://instance_external_ip:9200" from my workstation's CL I get a 'Connection refused'.

Elasticsearch is clearly running, since I can curl it from within the instance at localhost:9200, and I can access it via cerebro on my workstation.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the Elasticsearch application is listening on port 9200 using netstat command and adding the atup options to show the TCP and UDP connexions, all sockets and the PID of the process:

```
netstat -atup
```

Check if the Firewall Rules are correctly configured for ingress connections, to the related port and if it’s correctly applied on the network that your instance is running.